# MySQL Error 1215: unable to add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have looked everywhere about this error and read plenty of possible solutions but I still can't figure out what's wrong with my script.

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

**SQL Code:**

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `mydb`.`MARINE`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`MARINE` (
      `EDIPI` DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
      `LastName` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      `FirstName` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      `MiddleInitial` CHAR(1) NULL,
      `Rank` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
      `MOS` DECIMAL(4) NOT NULL,
      `BATTLE_SPACE_Company` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
      `BATTLE_SPACE_Section/Platoon` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`EDIPI`),
      INDEX `fk_MARINE_BATTLE_SPACE1_idx` (`BATTLE_SPACE_Company` ASC, `BATTLE_SPACE_Section/Platoon` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_MARINE_BATTLE_SPACE1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`BATTLE_SPACE_Company` , `BATTLE_SPACE_Section/Platoon`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`BATTLE_SPACE` (`Company` , `Section/Platoon`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

```
CREATE TABLE `battle_space` (
  `Company` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Section/Platoon` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Company`,`Location`,`Section/Platoon`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Can you indent please?

Comment: @Rahul I accidentally rejected your edit. Sorry.

Comment: @Drew Ok np.. I have updated many thing in my answer. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Dave Do the tables you are setting FK constraints on exist before you are trying to create the MARINE table?

Comment: Dave don't do that you just clobbered the formatting. I rolled it back

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of Problems.

1. Incldue **DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;** in **MARINE** table definition as well.
2. You need to have the **Columns** in **Foreign Key** in **Same Order** as **Parent** table.

`username@mydb[temp]>CREATE TABLE battle_space (
   Company char(1) NOT NULL,
   Location varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   Section varchar(2) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (Company,Location,Section)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)`

`username@mydb[temp]>CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MARINE (
     EDIPI DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
     LastName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
     FirstName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
     MiddleInitial CHAR(1) NULL,
     Rank VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
     MOS DECIMAL(4) NOT NULL,
     BATTLE_SPACE_Company CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
     BATTLE_SPACE_Section VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
     Location VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (EDIPI),
     INDEX fk_MARINE_BATTLE_SPACE1_idx (BATTLE_SPACE_Company ASC , BATTLE_SPACE_Section ASC , Location),
     CONSTRAINT fk_MARINE_BATTLE_SPACE1 FOREIGN KEY (BATTLE_SPACE_Company , Location , BATTLE_SPACE_Section)
         REFERENCES battle_space (Company , Location , Section)
         ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 )  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)`